# Linq to XML delete parent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to delete a parent from a element in XML.

My XML:

```
<root>
<Element1 ManagementID="10" />
<Users>
    <UserID ManagementID="10">
        <Identification IDValue="1" />
        <!-- More elements Here -->
    </UserID>
</Users>
<!-- More Users elements Here -->
```

I find my user my its IDValue:

```
XElement user = (from el in document.Root.Elements("Users").Elements("UserID ").Elements("Identification")
                   where (string)el.Attribute("IDValue") == myID
                   select el).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, I would like to remove all the user.Parent.Parent
I mean delete the element:

```
<Users>
    <UserID ManagementID="10">
        <Identification IDValue="1" />
        <!-- More elements Here -->
    </UserID>
</Users>
```

** I'll have many Users elements, that's why first I look for the identification IDValue

I found the solution for who needs it:
I already had the node from my linq so

```
user.Parent.Parent.Remove()
```

Comment: Please see the XML under the Parent.Parent. I put an example there

Comment: I want to remove element <Users>. My query finds element <Identification> its parent is <UserID>. Then its parent is <Users>. Sorry, that is what I mean by Parent.Parent

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = document.Root
        .XPathSelectElements("//UserId")
        .FirstOrDefault(userId => userId.Element("Identification").Attribute(XName.Get("IDValue")).Value == myID);
```

Comment: I got the message XDocument does not contain a definition for XPathSelectElements

Comment: Are you sure? XDocument.Root is the root XElement for the XDoc, and I'm staring at the code that's verified by Intellisense.

Comment: [Proof](https://i.imgur.com/CvluvN3.png)

Are you sure you're using the latest code update?

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
            List<XElement> users = document.Descendants("Users")
                .Where(user => user.Elements("Identification")
              .Where(el => (string)el.Attribute("IDValue") != myID)
              .Any()).ToList();

           XElement element1 = document.Descendants("Element1").FirstOrDefault();
           element1.ReplaceNodes(users);
```

Comment: I think it do not delete the node

Comment: The old code just got the user to keep.  Now updated code to replace.

Comment: I see, but I'm looking for Remove() the node

Comment: What I did was to filter rows that didn't have the required id.  Then replace with the filtered list.  So the id was removed by the filter.